# Get list elements into an array - Cucumber/Ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I am trying to test a list on a web page using Cucumber and Ruby.

The list changes (dependant on user input) basically, I want to grab all the item into an array - I then wan to ensure that the list is in alphabetical order.   Ideas anybody

Comment: Give more information, like how are you doing it now and some may come up with the idea why it is not working.

Comment: list_items = page.all('div.all-sports ul').collect(&:text)
  list_items.sort.should == list_items
  puts list_items.join("\n") --- this code still does not detect alphabetical erros??

Answer (score 1):

Use capybara's `all` method to find elements on page:

```
elements_array = page.all(:css, 'li')
```

See [corresponding API docs](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Finders%3aall).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Capybara and CSS selectors, this will give you an array contains text of each element in the list:

```
list_items = page.all('li').collect(&:text)
```

If you're using RSpec you can confirm they are sorted with:

```
list_items.sort.should == list_items
```

(you might write a be_sorted RSpec matcher to make that cleaner).